# Trying to create a modal window with independent scroller

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a modal window with its own scrollbar.The scroller usually controlled the main page rather than the contents inside the `modalwindow`.I've added a `jsfiddle` to show where Ive reaached with this. The content inside the `div "test"` should be the one determining the height of modal window.But `scrollbar` doesnt work properly with my code.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WzA4y/24/)

like the pinterest.com or twitter modal window..

Comment: You mean, like when the Facebook Photo Viewer is open, the modal window moves on its own (by using the main scrollbar), but the background content stays in place as you scroll?

Comment: actually... more like http://pinterest.com/   it replaces the original browser scroller

Comment: Exactly the same effect... I have been trying to get this right myself. I think it works by turning the main scroller off, placing a `<div>` over it. This `<div>` would contain the modal window, and would then scroll if it is too long. As for the way in which it disables the scroller (instead of hiding it), I have no cooking clue.

Comment: To see what I mean, open Pinterest up in Chrome. Then open up a pin, and right click on the transparent background and inspect the element. You'll see a `div` called `zoomScroll`.

Comment: is it possible to place a div over main scrller?? as far as I know, it is not possible... right?

Comment: No, you should set the `overflow` property of `<body>` (or `<html>`) to `hidden`, and then place a `div` that covers the entire page. Inside that `div`, create your modal window. Note, however, that this may not work with all modal plugins.

Comment: it is set to hidden in my example..

Comment: See [this](http://www.ehow.com/how_11367747_prevent-background-scrolling-displaying-modal-dialog-jquery.html) for more information about the technique.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this jQuery plugin: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/.

You should use a div container for a modal popup and call the jscrollpane plugin for the div.